# Java - paintComponent memory leak

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm working in a Java GUI project right now (a small Dungeon Crawler) using Swing and there seems to be a memory leak in my `paintComponent` method, but I can't make out what causes it:

```
class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage floor;
    private BufferedImage wall;
    private BufferedImage nullTile;
    private TileMap tileMap;

    private int centerImageX;
    private int centerImageY;

    public GamePanel(TileMap t) {
        //setTitle("Dungeon Crawler v0.1a");
        tileMap=t;
        setSize(800,600);

        centerImageY=(this.getHeight()/2)-16;
        centerImageX=(this.getWidth()/2)-16;

        setVisible(true);

        try {
            floor = ImageIO.read(new File(TileType.Floor.toString()+".png"));
            wall = ImageIO.read(new File(TileType.Wall.toString()+".png"));
            BufferedImage nullTileIn = ImageIO.read(new File(TileType.Null.toString()+".png"));
            nullTile = new BufferedImage(nullTileIn.getWidth(),nullTileIn.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g = nullTile.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(nullTileIn,0,0,null);
            g.dispose();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Shit hit the fan");
        }



    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        for (int i=0;i<50;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<50;j++) {                
                    g.drawImage(typeToImage(tileMap.getTile(i, j).type), i*32, j*32, null);
            }
        }

        g.dispose();
    }

    private BufferedImage typeToImage(TileType t) {
        switch (t) {
            case Null:
                return nullTile;
            case Floor:
                return floor;
            case Wall:
                return wall;

        }
        return nullTile;
    }
}
```

`tileMap` is a two-dimensional array of `Tile` objects, but those don't change, so they're not the culprit, `typeToImage` contains a simple `switch-case`, that connects the values from the `TileType` enum to one of the `BufferedImage` objects that we're made in the constructor.

There is nothing else in the class that could cause a memory leak, but maybe you can help me find the source.

Comment: Doubt it is the cause of the leak but don't use `g.dispose()` on the Graphics object passed to the paintComponent(...) method. Only use dispose() if you create a Graphics object in the method, for example by use `g.createGraphics()`.

Comment: If you don't know what causes the leak, how do you know it happens in this method? Please post your full code. Maybe you're loading a new image each time typeToImage is called?

Comment: @ToddSewell this is the full code, minus a bit of old code that I commented out incase I need it later.

Comment: No I meant the full code, something that I could run. Just post the whole class here. I'm particularly interested in the typeToImage method.

Comment: And could you also reply to/take into account the comments that were already posted?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a memory leak in this code to me, but I can't test until later today. Why do you think there is one?

Comment: @ToddSewell memory keeps increasing every time paintComponent is called e.g. while moving the window around, I did find out (a few hours after asking this question) that the increases drastically slow down nearing a certain value.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) **I doubt there is really a memory leak. The JRE will only call the garbage collector if it feels it *necessary* to do so. Watching 'memory size' is premature optimisation.**

Answer (score 0):

I think `BufferedImage` causes the memory leak. I also have almost the similar situation. In a long running thread, I am painting a component. I am creating a new `BufferedImage` every time the function is called but after finishing the drawing the memory occupied by the `BufferedImage` is not garbage collected. As long as the application is running memory usages increase.

Technically, it is not the memory leak. GC does not clear the memory occupied by `BufferedImage` immediately. It clears memory when it is necessary (depending on your heap, stack, permspace, etc. allocation). You can test by tuning -Xmx parameter (whether there is any `OutOfMemoryError`).